# What's the difference between eth0:1 and 2nd eth0?

Tags: linux-networking

In Ubuntu server, I configured eth0:1 like this in /etc/network/interfaces file

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.111
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
        dns-search defaultdomain

iface eth0:1 inet static
        address 192.168.4.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I can see it using ifconfig:

```
eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:a9:7c:83  
          inet addr:192.168.4.1  Bcast:192.168.4.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

But I find another way, just use eth0 twice.

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.111
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
        dns-search defaultdomain

iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.4.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

This time I cannot see 192.168.4.1 by using ifconfig, but ping this IP address is still okay.
What't the difference between above two ways?

Comment: @c4f4t0r  What to you think is wrong with the second example?

Answer (score 1):

forgot my comment, in the first case you have an virtual interface alias ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.4.1/24 up and in the second case you have an secondary ip address ip addr add 192.168.4.1/24 dev eth0

but in both case are secondary address, the first is in the old style and second is new configuration style using the ip command

Comment: Where can I find the doc about that?

Comment: I suggest you start by reading man interfaces.

Comment: The old eth0:1 alias style is deprecated and should not be used on modern systems. But there are still many old tutorials out on the Internet...

Comment: @MichaelHampton deprecated since 2014, still many people keep using them. This is really confusing. I saw in the kernel doc that they are deprecated, just didn't know that this is the case also since 2014